# What is the most logical way of setting up multiple UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue

There are 3 ways for walking around pages of an iOS app.

1. Using `main.storyboard` and connecting view controllers by segues.(relate view controllers by drag and stretch view controllers)
2. Coding them. This means we have one storyboard file and have view controller classes for each pages and by coding connect them to gather.
3. Creating classes by `UIViewController` protocols for each pages and connect them together by coding without storyboard files.

Now, please can you explain to me which one of these is better and more logical?

Comment: your 2nd and 3rd way is same.... :)

Answer (score 1):

### As with all opinion based questions, it depends.

I personally **loathe** storyboards. They're clunky and horrible, and auto-layout is a nightmare (*the sheer number of problems on here that are caused by auto-layout is insane... but I digress*).

I prefer to hard code everything. It allows me to have much greater flexibility, is far more transparent and is much easier to debug when I'm setting up my app's layout, but it will obviously take longer.

However, using storyboards allows you to visualise your UI as you build it, which is why so many people (especially those who are new to Xcode) love them. Of course you can't do *everything* purely through storyboards, **you will have to code the logic behind them at some point or another**. Therefore I would suggest getting used to managing views and segues programatically, even if you do want to use storyboards.

Also if you do decide to use storyboards, [as Andrey says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34874271/2976878), you should be splitting up your storyboard files if you are working with a large number of views. They can get bloated and laggy with too many views in them (another reason why I hate them).

Answer (score 0):

You can also have multiple storyboard files for each "group of functionality".

I think it actually depends on how big your application is (how many views and controllers you need). For small single page application with a few views you can use one storyboard and segues.

But wenn the app becomes more complicated you should split views in separate storyboards and instantiate view controllers programmatically without segues.

For small views you can still use xibs.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Storyboards**: this way is the best to use providing a smooth GUI for developers and clean graphical flow to follow your app structure.
2. **Using Storyboards but connecting controllers programmatically**: why using this way rather than using the (1) choice for you! if you need to customize transitions among view-controllers, you can still do that in storyboard and create a customized segue for that then assigning it, so (1) is sill the better.
3. **Not using storyboards**: this one was traditionally used earlier when storyboards were not yet introduced, now you can use it but still (1) is the best and easiest way to use and faster for development.

Hope that helps (go for the first choice)

Answer (score 0):

I personally use both, I prefer to code, however I tend to use a mix of story board and code as like originalUser2 states that auto-layout sucks, but story board can be used to keep individual file sizes down.